# Java apache commons CLI, repetitive options - need the last entered arguments

Tags: java, duplicates, command-line-interface

I'm just starting out with apache commons CLI in Java and could have CLI options which are repeated.  Does apache commons automatically process?

Ex. (program -w arg 1 arg2 -w arg1 arg2).

I need the last pair of args assigned to option -w.  Does apache commons automatically overwrite the args for repeated options?

Answer (score 0):

Apache common takes in the first option/argument unless looped over.
Just use two for loops, compare element at 'j' with element at 'i', return the element at 'j' and and element at 'j+1'

```
String[] options = {"-a","123","-b","456","-c","789","-a", "000"};
      List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();

      for(int i = 0; i<options.length; i++){
         for(int j = i+1; j<options.length; j++) {
             if(options[i].equals(options[j])){
                 res.add(options[j]);
                 res.add(options[j+1]);
             }
         }
      }
      
      for(String a: res)
        System.out.println(a);
```

The above code prints

```
"-a" and "000"
```

which is your repeated option w/argument